# List subscriptions

Tags: c#, azure

My question is simple: is it possible to list all subscriptions a user has access to, using an API?

My goal is to create an application where the user gets a list of his subscriptions and can select a subscription to view all his deployed applications.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to do so as no public API is available. What you could possibly do is ask your users to provide you with publish profile file (if they can do that). You could then parse the profile file, get the subscription ids and management certs and use them in Service Management REST API.

Comment: Thanks, but which publish profile file exactly are you referring to?

Comment: It's an XML file that you download when deploying through Visual Studio. It contains information about all the subscriptions (and corresponding management certificates) associated with a Live Id. See this post for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/05/10/downloading-windows-azure-publish-settings-subscription-configuration-file.aspx.

Comment: The following might shed a bit more light on this, but ultimately Guarav is right - you will need to get that list from (or through) or users. depending on your situation you may be bale to embed the download of the file in your application, but it will require the user's login to the management portal.     http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/azure-subscriptions-in-powershell-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is available but not documented yet.  If you carefully look at open source Powershell Cmdlets and the Management Library Clients (which are both under Azure account on GitHub) you will see that it is being used. :-)

I believe it only works with OAuth/AD authentication to the Azure REST API, not certificate based authentication (but I might be wrong).

The request looks like this:

```
GET https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptions
```

On authenticating to Azure with OAuth, check out my blog post:

https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/azure-rest-api-with-oauth2/